# How to play multiple videos from sqlite nonsimultaneous (queued) to videoView via loop?

Tags: android, sqlite, while-loop, android-videoview

I am making a finger sign language app.
I have managed to get the substrings of a string from the user input.
Now, each letter has corresponding video file from my sqlite and I want it to play on video view one at a time after each letter.

table:

|letter | videofilename|

|  a    | lettera      |

|  b    | letterb       |

|  c    | letterc      | and so on.

```
 public void fingerspell(View v) {
    CharSequence charSequence = etsearch.getText();
    String s = charSequence.toString();
    int startingletter = 0;
    int endingletter = 1;
    String desiredString;
    int wordlength = etsearch.length();
        do{

        desiredString = s.substring(startingletter, endingletter);
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tblletters WHERE letter like '" + desiredString + "'", null);
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), desiredString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                String video = c.getString(1);
                int videoResource = getResources().
                        getIdentifier(video, "raw", getPackageName());
                String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + videoResource;
                videoview.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
                videoview.start();
                videoview.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        //can't put startingletter++ here
                    }
                });


                startingletter++;
                endingletter++;
            }
         startingletter++;
            endingletter++;
    }while(startingletter<wordlength);
}
```

Only the toast works, It does play the first video but doesn't play the next.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way, I am not really sure if this is the proper coding but its working now. Based on what  understood, I'm looping the videoview.setOnCompletionListener even if it is already a loop and  I also declared the incrementing variables as global so it can be accessed from inner class.I am new to programming.

```
CharSequence charSequence = etsearch.getText();
        String s = charSequence.toString();
        int startingletter = 0;
        String desiredString;
        int wordlength = etsearch.length();
        final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        while (startingletter < wordlength) {
            desiredString = s.substring(startingletter, startingletter + 1);
            list.add(desiredString);
            startingletter++;
        }


        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), list.get(3), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        listsize = list.size();
        pogi = list.get(0);

        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), pogi, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tblletters WHERE letter like '" + pogi + "'", null);
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            String video = c.getString(1);
            int videoResource = getResources().
                    getIdentifier(video, "raw", getPackageName());
            String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + videoResource;
            videoview.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
            videoview.start();
        }


        videoview.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                halimaw++;
                if (halimaw < listsize) {
                    pogi = list.get(halimaw);

                    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tblletters WHERE letter like '" + pogi + "'", null);
                    c.moveToNext();
                    String video = c.getString(1);
                    int videoResource = getResources().
                            getIdentifier(video, "raw", getPackageName());
                    String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + videoResource;
                    videoview.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
                    videoview.start();
                } else {
                    halimaw = 0;
                    pogi = "";
                }
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "tapos na", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```